# Complex object as a queryparameter in in java rest application

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson, query-string

I need to be able to query a resource with a filter with many parameters (all optionals)

my url specification is something like this :

```
GET http://something/version/resource?f={"param1":"1","param2":"something else", "param3":"tomato"
```

I tried two approaches:

1. `@XmlRootElement` so I created a class filter and annotated it with the `@XmlRootElement` but the parameters are not parsed into my class.

```java
@XmlRootElement    
MyClassFilter{
   String param1;
   String param2;
   ..........

}
```

2. `@BeanParam` so I removed the `@XmlRootElement` annotation and I put a `@QueryParam` annotation for every field in the class and in the resource method I put the `@BeanParam` one.

```java
MyClassFilter{
   @QueryParam("param1")
   String param1;
   @QueryParam("param2")
   String param2;
   ..........

}
```

I get `null` objects with both methods. Could someone point me to the right direction? I usually consume the services so I don't have much experience on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, in my get method I receive the filter as a string:

```
@QueryParam(value = "f") String f
```

and I parse it using the ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
EntityFilter filter = mapper.readValue(f, EntityFilter.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParamConverterProvider`.

```
@Provider
public class JSONParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
        if(rawType.equals(MyObject.class)){
            return (ParamConverter<T>) new JSONParamConverter();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```